# Category Tree View / Accordion on homepage- Magento 1.9

Tags: css, magento, treeview

I want to have a 2 column layout with left bar on my homepage. In the left column, I want a list of categories shown in a tree view for a particular category of the main menu (Main menu has links like Contact Us etc which I do not want in the left tree view). I tried a number of solutions online, but nothing worked. Some of them listed the categories and subcategories, but without any CSS.
Anyone tried solving this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no module that fit your needs, a little development should be done to retrieve the result you are looking for.

You could use the `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/navigation/left.phtml` block for this. In that block subcategories from the current category are shown, normally this block only is shown on listpages with subcategories.
You can add this block to the homepage and replace `<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories() ?>` with custom code which retrieves the categories/menu structure.

Comment: I have written a code that recursively gets the categories and subcategories I want. But am not able to put them in proper css for treeview.

Comment: You could look at some existing shops and recreate the structure and copy the css. It's not that difficult.
Or just use a plugin for that: http://www.jstree.com/